# Duplicate in Gatsby path to markdown file for blog post

Tags: reactjs, path, markdown, gatsby

I am editing this Gatsby starter to make a personal website: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/starters/rolwin100/rolwinreevan_gatsby_blog/

Note that the problem I'm having with my site also happens when I develop the starter (with no changes made).

My desired outcome is pretty simple, I just want to be able to click on a blog post at site-name.com/blog/post-name that works. So, I set the path in my markdown files to be blog/post-name, replicating the starter exactly. However, when I run gatsby develop and click on the posts, the weirdest thing happens, For ex, from running the starter I get: There's not a page yet at /blog/blog/code-splitting-in-react (pictured fully below). But the page /blog/code-splitting-in-react **does** exist and when you adjust the url to that it brings up the page perfectly.

So the question is-- where is that extra 'blog' coming from in the path and how do I get rid of it??

[error messages when I click on a blog post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bs8Eh.png)

Answer (score 0):

You said that you are setting the url to `blog/post-name`. That is a relative path. It is going to start from whatever url you currently are. For example if you are in `http://example.com/bla/foo` you'll end in `http://example.com/bla/foo/blog/post-name`. You need to add a slash at the beginning: `/blog/post-name`.